# Hive SQL query by status change

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

| vehicle | record_time | charging_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 14:55:54.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 15:00:00.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 15:16:10.0 | 3 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 15:37:11.0 | 0 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 15:40:34.0 | 0 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 15:41:50.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 15:45:30.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 15:51:46.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 15:57:16.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 15:57:39.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 15:57:47.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:02:41.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:02:48.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:08:03.0 | 3 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:17:34.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:24:18.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:27:43.0 | 2 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:29:22.0 | 0 |
| 12100000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:32:44.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:34:17.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:34:36.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:35:02.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:35:08.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:41:28.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:42:34.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:46:00.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:46:23.0 | 3 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 16:46:31.0 | 2 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 16:46:48.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 17:14:27.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000001 | 2022-12-28 17:14:41.0 | 0 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 2022-12-28 17:18:58.0 | 2 |

`charging_state == 0`  means charging

I want to find out the count of all charge ends.

For each vehicle the previous data `charging_state == 0` and the next data `charging_state != 0`.

The result of the sample data should be

| vehicle | count |
| --- | --- |
| TEST0000000000001 | 1 |
| 12100000000000002 | 1 |
| TEST0000000000002 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is hive, you can use `lead()` to get next charging status and then compare them to calculate change of status.

```
select vehicle, 
sum( case when charging_state=0 and nvl(next_charging_state,0)<>0 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from (
select vehicle, charging_state, lead(charging_state) over (partition by vehicle order by vehicle,record_time ) as next_charging_state from mytable) rs
group by 1
```

Inner query will calculate a row and next row's status and Outer query will compare them and get a count of status change from 0 to anything else.